# How is chromaticity and luminance separated in the CIE xyY colour space?

Tags: graphics, photo

The parameters of the CIE xyY colour space are defined in terms of the parameters of the CIE XYZ colour space as follows:

```
x = X / (X + Y + Z),
y = Y / (X + Y + Z),
z = Z / (X + Y + Z) = 1 - x - y.
```

The XYZ colour space was designed such that the Y parameter is a measure of the luminance of a colour. Multiple sources (such as [The CIE XYZ and xyY Color Spaces](https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs148-10-summer/docs/2010--kerr--cie_xyz.pdf)) explain that the xyY colour space separates chromaticity and luminance, where the x and y parameters of the specify the chromaticity of a colour, and Y specifies the luminance. They explain that as the three normalised parameters sum to 1, then only two are needed to specify the chromaticity.

My (basic and recent) understanding is that chromaticity and luminance together fully specify a colour, and that x and y alone are not enough to fully specify a colour, and so it is useful to include the untransformed Y as the third parameter that specifies the luminance directly. However, I am confused as to how x and y together specify the chromaticity, and not the luminance, especially as they depend on the value of Y.

I have been unable to find an intuitive explanation for this online, but I figure that I may be trying to understand this in the wrong way.